# Сшить два списка, Python

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, списки

Имеем два списка:

```
a = [x1, x2, x3 ... xn]
b = [y1, y2, y3 ... yn]
```

Надо получить список (по типу "молния")

```
[x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, ... xn,yn]
```

Желательно покороче и оптимально.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))
```

**UPD**
Без импортов

```
[item for sublist in zip(a, b) for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Хотелось бы без использования сторонних библиотек

Comment: itertools - это не сторонняя библиотека: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: добавил вариант без импорта в ответ

Comment: list(chain(*zip(a, b)))

Answer (score 2):

```
c = []
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    c += [i,j]
```