# Складывание двух списков

Tags: python-3.x

Как называется функция, складывающая списки `[1,3,5,7]` и `[0,2,4,6]` в `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` ?

Comment: честное слово, вопрос слишком просто, чтобы его сюда писать. гугл Вам в помощь

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev человеку, не знающему нужных терминов, составить правильный запрос будет трудно

Comment: @andreymal это у Вас сарказм такой?)

Comment: первая же ссылка сказала мне, что нужно их просто сложить дгух с другом с = а + в

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev и получится неправильный результат

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Сшить два списка, Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580305). `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip([0,2,4,6], [1,3,5,7])))` → `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Comment: А че надо-то - сложить через одного или чтобы результат был по возрастанию? Это разные задачи и у них разные решения.